# IE Redirect Method

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Use Different HTML for IE

I have developed a CSS Grid Site that works with all browsers except IE and have tried Autoprefixer which made improvements but did not fix all problems, some of which may not be Grid related. I am looking for recommendations to redirect **ALL** IE browsers to a completely different HTML file and would appreciate recommendations to do so. I already have separate HTML and CSS files that work with IE. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: IE does not have proper css grid support: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this on another post and it seems to work well:

```
    <<!-- For IE <= 9 -->
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "https://google.com";
</script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- For IE > 9 -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.navigator.msPointerEnabled) {
        window.location = "http://bobabend.com/index-old-as-of-3-7-2019.html";
    }
</script>
```